# Executing SQL statement in ASEISQL with UNIX scripts

Tags: unix, isql

Since I am new to unix scripting. I am running a SQL statement in ASE ISQL, and if SQL statement gives some result then I need to mail that result to a particular users. And if SQL is not returning any result then mail should not be sent.
The Sample Script I have wriiten is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
isql -U$DBO -S$DSQUERY -D$DBNAME -P$PASSWORD << END 
go
select * from 'Table'
go
if (@@rowcount !=0)

mailx -s "Hello" XYZ@gmail.com 


END
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: mailx is a unix command. See if your DB has a way to call external programs. Then you have to figure out how to assemble your mail msg with SQL strings. Do you need a closing `endif` (or similar) to close off the scope of your conditional? Maybe not, but again, consult your DB's programming manual. It would also be possible to capture SQL output to file (or env var), and have shell script supply conditional logic for mail or no-mail. With your 0% acceptrate, I'm not inclined to spend time writing up anything further. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to capture the output of the SQL into a shell variable, and then test the result before sending the email, roughly like:

```
#!/bin/ksh
num=$(isql -U$DBO -S$DSQUERY -D$DBNAME -P$PASSWORD << END 
select count(*) from 'Table'
go
END
)

if [ "$num" -gt 0 ]
then mailx -s "Hello" XYZ@gmail.com < /dev/null
fi
```

I am assuming that the `isql` program will only print the number and not any headings or other information.  If it is more verbose, then you have to do a more sensitive test.

Note, too, that `COUNT(*)` is quicker and more accurately what you're after than your 'select everything and count how many rows there were' version.

---

> Actually my problem is if my SQL statement is returning any result then only that resultset should be sent in a mail.

Then I'd use:

```
#!/bin/ksh
tmp=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/results.$$
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

isql -U$DBO -S$DSQUERY -D$DBNAME -P$PASSWORD << END > $tmp
select * from 'Table'
go
END

if [ -s $tmp ]
then mailx -s "Hello" XYZ@gmail.com < $tmp || exit 1
fi
rm -f $tmp
trap 0
exit 0
```

This captures the results in a file.  If the file is not empty (`-s`) then it sends the file as the body of an email.  Please change the subject to something more meaningful.  Also, are you sure it is a good idea to send corporate email to a Gmail account?

Comment: Actually my problem is if my SQL statement is returning any result then only that resultset should be sent in a mail. If am writing script in the form :#!/bin/ksh isql -U$DBO -S$DSQUERY -D$DBNAME -P$PASSWORD << END |mailx -s "Hello" XYZ@gmail.com go select * from 'Table' go END...then the result of SQL statement is sent in the mail. But I need to write script in such manner first it should check the SQL statement result if it is other than Blank then that result is sent in the mail.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan your script worked. And I have put that gmail address just for sample.

Comment: FYI: the domains example.com and example.org are reserved for use in examples.  Hence, you can always use someone@example.com (or something similar) as an example email address.  I suspected that was an example, but funnier things have been known.